# Why Is MediaRecorder Output File Being Cut Off

Tags: android, python, google-app-engine

I have a very simple Activity to record audio using [MediaRecorder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html). Basic start/stop functions

```
// start
recorder.prepare();
recorder.start();

// stop
recorder.stop();
recorder.release();
recorder = null;
```

I pass the output file to Google App Engine via [org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html) in a Blob datastore.

```
// AsyncTask doInBackground
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(DEV_SERVER);
ByteArrayOutputStream outstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(
    HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

InputStream audio_is = cr.openInputStream(working_uri);
int nRead;
byte[] data = new byte[16384];
while ((nRead = audio_is.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
    outstream.write(data, 0, nRead);
}
outstream.flush();
ByteArrayBody body = new ByteArrayBody(outstream.toByteArray(),
    POST_TEMP_FILENAME);
reqEntity.addPart("uploaded", body);
httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

The result is a full file on the sdcard, but when the file is stored on the server it is corrupt.

Is it possible I'm not reading the bytes correctly? Or is it more a matter of Google App Engine not storing the Blob correctly?

Here is the receiving python code:

```
def post(self):
    entry = models.Entry()
    entry.content = db.Blob(self.request.get("uploaded"))
    entry.put();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out everything was working just fine. It was my desktop player VLC that wasn't decoding the file correctly. AMR/3GP audio is horrible.